# How to avoid selecting DataGridRow in ParentDataGrid by Clicking in DataGridDetailsPresenter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, selectionchanged

I have a DataGrid (ParentDataGrid) with a DataGridDetailsPresenter. In the DataGridDetailsPresenter I have another DataGrid (ChildDataGrid). If I select a Row in the ChildDataGrid the surrounding DataGridRow of the ParentDataGrid is selected too.

I get that both the ParentDataGrid and the ChildDataGrid throws the SelectionChanged event. I tried to deselect selection in ParentDataGrid. But then the primary selection in the ParentDataGrid is changed. Therefore I want to avoid selecting DataGridRow in ParentDataGrid.

How to avoid selecting DataGridRow in ParentDataGrid by Clicking in DataGridDetailsPresenter?

This is my DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyViewModel}">
<DataTemplate.Resources>...
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border ...>
                  <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                      <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                      </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                      </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>

                      <DataGridRowHeader Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" .../>
                      <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" .../>
                      <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" .../>

                  </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                </Border ...>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</DataTemplate.Resources>

<Grid ...>

<DataGrid x:Name="ParentDataGrid" ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>...</DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ...>
                <DataGrid x:Name="ChildDataGrid"...>...</DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

</DataGrid>

</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Where is another DataGrid in DataGridDetailsPresenter ? Post complete xaml and if possible some sample viewmodel for binding.

Comment: The child DataGrid is defined in the DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate. I added the name now. This child DataGrid is presented in the DataGridDetailsPresenter. The ViewModel is not important. I posted it to show that I'm using DataTemplates. Both DataGrids has some Items. These Items can be independent.

Comment: Child DG is in the DataTemplate of RowDetailsTemplate, from where your DataGridDetailsPresenter comes in picture.

Comment: I have reproduced ur issue, will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Handle `SelectedCellsChanged` event in your parent `DataGrid`.

```
private void DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DgrdParent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(DgrdParent.SelectedItem);
            if (row != null)
                row.IsSelected = false;
        }
```

And if you want to get the selected child `DataGrid`, you can use its `SelectionChanged` event.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="DgrdParent" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" CurrentCellChanged="DgrdParent_CurrentCellChanged_1" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" SelectionChanged="DgrdParent_SelectionChanged_1" SelectedCellsChanged="DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged_1" >
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridDetailsPresenter">
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid x:Name="DgrdChild" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" SelectionChanged="DataGridInner_SelectionChanged_1" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>            
    </DataGrid>
```

Handler :

```
   private void DataGridInner_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DataGridInner_SelectionChanged_1 > Original source = " + ((DataGrid)sender).Name);
    }
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing. I add a behavior and handle the SelectionChanged event. I clear the selection of the parent DataGrid in the event handler. But this come to two new problems. 1st It's not very clean code to get the correct situation. Did the user click in the child DataGrid or did the user select a row in the parent DataGrid. 2nd the primary selection is changed. And I didn't find a way to get the old selection.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to handle the selection. I want to avoid it. Is there no way to avoid bubbling the click event from child DataGrid to parent DataGrid. I thought about putting a Border between DataGridCellsPresenter and the DataGridDetailsPresenter and set the IsHitTestVisible property to true to catch the Click event. But I didn't get it working. Do you think this way should be possible?

Comment: @Christopher Put your inner DataGrid in a Button and set IsHitTestVisible to false for this inner DataGrid. See if this solves your problem.

Comment: I can't select a row in the inner DataGrid if I set IsHitTestVisible to false for the inner DataGrid. If I don't set IsHitTestVisible to false it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: I tried it. But then I can't select any thing in the inner DataGrid. The inner DataGrid is disabled for any click. I have to select rows in the inner DataGrid. And if I click on the outer DataGrid I want to select things in the outer DataGrid. Both have to be possible.